# PhpStorm inspection errors for thrown exception

Tags: php, exception, phpstorm, docblocks

I am trying to catch a custom exception, but keep getting an `Exception 'CustomException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block` inspection error for the following scenario:

```
class CustomException extends Exception { }

class Test {

    /**
     * @throws CustomException
     */

    public function willFail()
    {
        throw new CustomException('I failed');
    }

}

$test = new Test;

try {

    $test->willFail();

} catch (CustomException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

The above example *works* exactly as expected, aside from PhpStorm giving me the inspection error.

I've searched everywhere and can't find out how to fix this without disabling the inspection entirely. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: works fine on my box.  What do you mean 'Inspection error' ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I've added a screenshot to my question. I hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: not able to duplicate : PhpStorm 2020.1.4, osx, php 7.2.8

Comment: of course, there is always the jetbrains classic for every bizarro you will encounter.  Reindex and restart.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thanks for checking. I just updated my version of PhpStorm to the same version as you 2020.1.4, and I am still experiencing this issue... strange...

Comment: Looks like PhpStorm is failing to read your PHPDoc. If you hover over the method name (where it's defined), does it show that it throws that exception (on the tooltip)?

Comment: @Jeto Yes, it does show that it throws that exception on the tooltip. I've also updated the screenshot above and the example code, which is the entirety of the file in question.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem themselves in the future, I'm posting the solution to this problem.

This was fixed by updating "Call tree analysis depth" to "1" in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP`. Click on the "Analysis" tab and update the setting there.

[image: Screenshot]